# Can AntMiner L3+ mine any scrypt coins or just lite coin

Tags: litecoin, antminer

I am planning to buy ant miner l3+. Can AntMiner L3+ mine any scrypt coins or just lite coin?
Should I buy Antminer s9 or L3+?
However, I can only afford one piece of anyone.

Answer (score 2):

The L3+ is the best option *right now* (however if you're ordering now, you won't get a new one for some time, and the second hand ones are being resold for huge profits), however this will change as more of them are made/released.

The L3+ is a Scrypt miner, so it could in theory mine any Scrypt based coins, Litecoin being the big one.

Bitmain don't appear to be shipping anything out any time soon, Avalon (http://canaan.io) or Ebit (http://miner.ebang.com.cn) also sell alternative miners, they're not as power efficient as the S9 (and slower), but cheaper, so if you're dipping your feet into the water to test the temperature, it's an alternative.